# Python - Declaração de uma variavel em try

Tags: python

Estou a tentar criar um menu em Python e me deparei com uma parte de cálculos matemáticos em que gostaria de inserir uma condição de erro caso o utilizador inserisse uma letra num local onde só pode receber um número.

Estou a utilizar loops e o meu problema é que eu ao utilizar a função `try`, tenho que declarar uma variável dentro dessa função para que esta seja executada. Eu acho, mas, em seguida - mais à frente no programa -, não consigo "chamá-la" porque a mesma foi declarada localmente!

Aqui está o meu código de exemplo:

```
while loop2:
    try:
        a = int(input("Introduza o primeiro número: \n"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Introduza um número inteiro!")
    else:
        break
    try:
        b = int(input("Introduza o segundo número: \n"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Introduza um número inteiro!")
    else:
        break
    oper = str(input("Introduza o sinal de operação: \n"))
    if oper == "+":
        print(f"O resultado é: {a + b }!")
```

Na última linha de código que exemplifiquei, nem `"a"` e nem `"b"` estão definidos. Logo, não vou conseguir fazer nenhuma operação!

Comment: Por que afirma que a variável não existirá fora do `try`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua premissa está errada.

O bloco `try/except` não cria um novo contexto de variáveis, ou seja, qualquer variável que você definir dentro do seu bloco `try` irá existir fora do bloco também. Veja o exemplo:

```py
try:
  number = int("42")
except TypeError:
  pass

print(f"Número: {number}")  # Número 42
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/UpsetTechnoChief#main.py) ou no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/TqW5nz)</sup>

O que acontece é que você utilizou a estrutura `else` do `try/except/else` e colocou um `break` nele. O `else` dessa estrutura **sempre** será chamada quando nenhuma exceção for lançada no `try` e quando executada irá parar seu laço de repetição. Ou seja, sempre que o usuário informar um número válido, cairá no `else` e seu laço de repetição irá finalizar, nunca chegando no seu `print` onde supostamente as variáveis não existiam.

Para o seu problema, não há necessidade de utilizar o `else` no `try`.

Answer (score 2):

Uma das possíveis formas para se resolver esta questão é:

```
while True:
    try:
        a = int(input('Introduza o primeiro número: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Introduza um número inteiro!')

while True:
    try:
        b = int(input('Introduza o segundo número: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Introduza um número inteiro!')

oper = input('Introduza uma das operações [+/-]: ')
while (len(oper) != 1) or (oper not in '+-'):
    print('Valor INVÁLIDO!')
    oper = input('Introduza uma das operações(+/-): ')

if oper == '+':
    soma = (a + b)
    print(f"O resultado é: {soma}")
else:
    subtracao = (a - b)
    print(f'O resultado é: {subtracao}')
```

Observe que neste código o **1º bloco while** verificar se o valor de **a** é um número inteiro. Caso positivo, o código armazena o valor digitado na variável `a`. Caso negativo, será solicitado novamente um valor inteiro para ser inserido na variável `a`.

No **2º bloco while** será verificado se o valor digitado, também é um valor inteiro. Caso positivo, o código armazena o valor digitado na variável `b`. Caso negativo, será solicitado novamente um valor inteiro para ser inserido na variável `b`.

Em seguida é solicitado o **carácter** para a operação. Caso o carácter digitado seja **único** e esteja contido na string **+-**, será realizada a operação de **Adição** ou **subtração**, respectivamente.

Comment: Até o momento eu só não dou um +1 porque falta explicar ao AP que em python "o bloco `try/except` não cria um novo contexto de variáveis". Por que tem que explicar isso? Por exemplo para um desenvolvedor que veio do *js* ele vem com a percepção de que o bloco `try/catch` cria o seu próprio contexto de variáveis e um código análogo `try{let a=10; throw Error}catch(e){console.log(a)}` ira gerar o erro *Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined*

Comment: @Augusto Vasques, Não expliquei a diferença entre o `try/except` do `PYTHON` e o `tra/catch` do `JAVA SCRIPT` pelo simples fato do autor da pergunta não ter se referido ao `JAVA SCRIPT` mas, sim, ao `PYTHON`.

Comment: Acho que não me expliquei direito, desculpe o mal entendido mas eu citei o `JAVA SCRIPT` como um exemplo, eu poderia citar exemplos outras linguagens que possuem o mesmo comportamento similar a contexto de variáveis portanto *JS* foi a escolha por ser algo de domínio comum compreensível a um maior número de usuários.

Comment: Quanto a urgência da explicação parte da premissa que o AP em sua pergunta explicitou o seguinte argumento: *... o meu problema é que eu ao utilizar a função try, tenho que declarar uma variável dentro dessa função para que esta seja executada.*

Comment: Eu acho, mas, em seguida - mais à frente no programa -, não consigo "chamá-la" porque a mesma foi declarada localmente!* e **esse argumento é falso** pois o [tratamento de exceção](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/errors.html) não cria contexto local de variáveis o que pode ser comprovado por esse [exemplo](https://repl.it/repls/WittyGrimIde) levando a crer que o AP está tendo dificuldades em se adaptar com o [modelo de execução python](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/executionmodel.html).

Comment: Desculpando o textão mas achei que devia explicar a lógica por detrás do meu primeiro comentário por acreditar que não fui sábio na escolha de palavras.

Comment: @Augusto Vasques, Boa tarde! Grande Abraço!